# Arduino real time control

Tags: arduino

I have a very specific problem, exactly with real time control. For example I try to write an application where I can edit min or max temperature that after reaching it , I will receive SMS with message.I'm wondering how to edit variables "on-the-fly" because, as I know Arduino IDE use it own libraries not this from C/C++, and I don't know how to get to SD card in Arduino too. Can someone help?

Comment: I think your question refers to a large part to hardware (gps shield, sd card shield) and should be better discussed on arduino.stackexchange.com, where are already similar questions.

Comment: sorry but... I couldn't understand what you want to do. What do you mean by "on the fly"? Why are you connecting this to the fact that arduino uses its own libraries (partially true)? And what is the problem with the SD card? Is it related to the "main" problem or you just put two questions in the same post?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign new values to max and min in your Arduino code

```
if (newTemp>max)
  max=newTemp;
else if (newTemp<min)
 min= newTemp;
```

To use the SD card add/import the SD library to your sketch code using the Library menu in the Arduino Ide or in Visual Studio